# Proguard is saying it can't find any classes

Tags: java, spring, maven, obfuscation, proguard

I'm using proguard with a spring mvc application and maven.

My pom.xml's build section looks like:

```
<build>
        <finalName>myapp</finalName>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                    <!--<options>-->
                        <!--<option>-keep public class</option>-->
                    <!--</options>-->
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}</injar>
                    <injar>${project.build.finalName}</injar>
                    <inFilter>com.myapp.*</inFilter>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
         </plugins>
```

I also tried:

```
<injar>${project.build.finalName}.war</injar>
```

When I run:

```
mvn clean install
```

Build failure message:

```
[proguard] Reading program war [/Users/me/dev/git/myproject/myapp/target/myapp.war] (filtered)
 [proguard] Error: The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you specify the proper '-injars' options?

ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.pyx4me:proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4:proguard (default) on project myapp: Obfuscation failed (result=1) -> [Help 1]
```

It seems to have picked up my jar correctly as the messages before show:

```
[INFO] --- proguard-maven-plugin:2.0.4:proguard (default) @ myapp ---
[INFO] execute ProGuard [-injars, '/Users/me/dev/gitserver/myproject/myapp/target/myapp.war'(!META-INF/maven/**,com.myapp.*), -outjars, '/Users/me/dev/git/myproject/myapp/target/myapp_pg.war', -libraryjars, ....
```

**Also, what options do you suggest I use?**  This is a spring mvc so I have annotations like:

1. @Autowired
2. @Service
3. @Repository
4. @Controller

So any of those classes/fields should not be renamed I would imagine.

(My goal is just to make it a headache to someone who decompiles, such that they can't just decompile and use the code.  Obfuscating will let them use it, but they won't be able to maintain the codebase unless they re-write it.  I don't have any fancy algorithms so I have nothing really to hide in that respect.)

**Update**

Let me be clear here, my spring mvc using maven for some reason (I'm new to maven) when doing a mvn clean install produces both a myapp.war file and a exploded war myapp/ (this is what I want to deploy in production, not the myapp.war file)

My myapp folder has:

```
/target/myapp/
/target/myapp/meta-inf (empty folder)
/target/myapp/web-inf
/target/myapp/web-inf/classes (com.myapp. ...)
/target/myapp/web-inf/lib/
/target/myapp/web-inf/ web.xml, application.xml (for spring)
/target/myapp/web-inf/views/
```

So proguard should be obfuscating in the /target/myapp/web-inf/classes folder right?
How do I tell it to do so?

**Update 2**

I'm getting this now:

OK, I am not getting:  failed to execute goal ...proguard .. Can't rename /Users/me/dev/git/project1/myapp/target/myapp/web-inf/classes (see my updates section for what I changed in my pom.xml)

I changed my pom.xml with:

```
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>

                <injar>${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes/</injar>
                <inFilter>com/myapp/**</inFilter>
            </configuration>
```

Comment: See my answer and workaround below, ProGuard doesn't support this particular configuration

Answer (score 5):

ProGuard filters work on file names, so

```
.....(!META-INF/maven/**,com.myapp.*)
```

probably won't match any class files. You probably want

```
.....(!META-INF/maven/**,com/myapp/**)
```

See [ProGuard manual > Usage > File Filters](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#filefilters)

Comment: Ah, yep, didn't notice that in his previous question (which started as a different question).

Comment: how do I point proguard to my exploded war and not the war file? i.e. `/target/myapp/WEB-INF/classes/`

Comment: I'm confused, is it expecting `meta-inf/maven/` to have my classes folder in there? or is it inspecting the packages?

Comment: OK, I am not getting:  failed to execute goal ...proguard .. Can't rename /Users/me/dev/git/project1/myapp/target/myapp/web-inf/classes (see my updates section for what I changed in my pom.xml)

Comment: "Can't rename ..." must be a message from Maven or from the pyx4me ProGuard plugin for Maven, not from ProGuard itself; so I don't know really. If ProGuard works, you should see some console messages "Reading program ...., Preparing output ...., Copying resources ....". ProGuard can only handle an output directory that is different from the input directory. Maybe the plugin is having problems with moving the results around.

Comment: So do you suggest I just run proguard using the command line and not the maven plugin?  I guess I could run it as an ant task using maven and just do things the more manual and explicit way?

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your entire pom?

Normally, Maven compiles to /target/classes (Even for WAR files) and the WAR plugin does the copy to web-inf/classes right before the package phase. You should *not* be manually compiling classes to web-inf/lib with Maven.

EDIT: OK this has take quite a bit of research, but I've found an answer for you. First, [according to the ProGuard documentation](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass), you should not have **ANY** classes in your war project:

> Notably, class files that are in the WEB-INF/classes directory in a
>   war should be packaged in a jar and put in the WEB-INF/lib directory

You need to refactor your project so your web classes are built in a separate jar. Once you have built that jar project, you must add it as a dependency in your war project.

Once I created that setup, I was successfully able to build a war project with the following configuration:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.pyx4me</groupId>
                <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>proguard</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <inFilter>com/example/**</inFilter>
                    <libs>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                        <lib>${java.home}/lib/jsse.jar</lib>
                    </libs>
                    <options>
                        <option>-keep class com.example.echo.EchoServlet</option>
                        <option>-injar ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.${project.packaging}</option>
                        <option>-outjar ${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-proguarded.${project.packaging}</option>
                    </options>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Note the "com.example.echo.EchoServlet". Since progaurd was going to change the name of my classes, I had to "keep" this servlet name so I could reference it in the WAR project's web.xml. If you use annotation based servlet configuration, I imagine this won't be necessary.

Comment: With annotations, he would have to -keepattributes, because proguard strips them by default.

Comment: ok I'll try this out, thanks for your help.  I tried pointing proguard to the target/classses as you suggested b4 and that didn't work, same error saying can't rename folder.

Comment: well dang, the bounty expired :( I hope this answer still solves your problem though. Be sure to accept if it works out or if you need any help setting up the other maven project!

Comment: @Blankman, if this does work for you, i'd appreciate an answer accept and/or upvote. I spent a few hours researching this for you. If it didn't work, let me know. Thanks!