# using Proguard in a Maven project with several modules

Tags: java, maven, obfuscation, vaadin, proguard

I can't make Proguard Maven plugin to obfuscate files in a web project. I tried some solutions on Stackoverflow - no luck.

My actual application is Vaadin-based packaged with Maven, but I created a sample demo project **https://github.com/taskadapter/projectX** for now to illustrate the problem.
My end goal is creating a web application WAR file with all maven modules (e.g. "util") and web app code (e.g. "SomeImportantHiddenClass") obfuscated.

the build fails with:

> [proguard] Error: The input doesn't contain any classes. Did you
>   specify the proper '-injars' options?

I saw http://maksim.sorokin.dk/it/2010/08/23/obfuscating-several-jars-in-one-single-maven-build-with-proguard/, but this does not make sense to me.
if I run proguard plugin on every maven module in my project separately, then how will other modules in the same project find required classes if they are all "messed up"?

I assume I need to add proguard execution to either root pom.xml or my web module, which actually packages stuff into a WAR file (see the project on GitHub).

"injar" option allows adding Jars to the obfuscation process, but I expected the plugin to find my modules and obfuscate them **without** me hardcoding "injar" values like  "../util/target/util.jar".

plus proguard documentation does not say anything about "injars" option, it only describes "injar" configuration parameter. neither of them works in this case.

I also saw [Proguard is saying it can't find any classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845406/proguard-is-saying-it-cant-find-any-classes) , but I'm not sure moving all the classes from "web" maven module to a separate one is the right solution and not sure it'll work anyway. I'll keep trying...

Comment: Try to run proguard at process-classes phase, it will obfuscate .class file before packaging, then you can add that .jar file into .war file or anywhere you want.

Comment: thanks, we just gave up on using that tool.

Comment: Actually, you can obfuscate your project using proguard with some twist. But it's great to hear that you found another way to solve it.

Comment: Could you close the question then?