# Error: Can't read (Can't process class (com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class))

Tags: proguard, maven-plugin

i am trying to obfuscate a project and i got the error:

```
[proguard] Error: Can't read [/home/yeser/calarken_obfus/target/rbtarti-{VERSION}.war(;;;;;;!META-INF/maven/**)] (Can't process class [com/ibm/icu/impl/data/LocaleElements_zh__PINYIN.class] (Unknown constant type [60] in constant pool))
```

I have no idea how to solve. I looked the sourceforge and saw that the problem comes from icu4j. But i couldn't exclude it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look if is similar ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8845406/proguard-is-saying-it-cant-find-any-classes

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't help. Thanks.